# Insert into an unknown mysql column

Tags: python

Am trying to insert values into a mysql table with unknown database columns that are present in the db but can be found - and are passed - from inside a loop, however I am still stuck and I get the error message. I have written sample code that reproduces the error and tries to generate the mysql query dynamically. Is there a simpler way to do this with mysql? Why is my code not running? The final query seems correct

Error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s)' at line 1
```

The far that I could imagine

```
from Learn.callmysql import mycursor, db

datte = {}
datte["schoolfee"] = "amount"
datte["student"] = "name"

testlist = ["parent", "bothnames"] #Notte this will be generated dynamically so I have no idea the variables in it, this is a sample
thelist = []
secondlist = ""

for value in testlist:
    datte[value] = "Bch" #here "Bch will be a real unknown value"

print("Final dictionary after adding degree is like: " + str(datte))

for value in datte:
    thelist.append(value)

breakdown = "("
count  = 0
total_count_should_be = len(thelist)
for value in thelist:
    if count == total_count_should_be -1:
        breakdown = breakdown + value + ")"
    else:
        breakdown = breakdown + value+","
    count = count + 1

first_part_of_query = breakdown

print("First part of the query will be like: " + first_part_of_query)

for index in range(len(thelist)):
    if index == 0:
        secondlist = secondlist + "(%s,"
    elif index == len(thelist)-1:
        secondlist = secondlist + "%s)"
    else:
       secondlist  = secondlist + "%s,"

second_part_of_the_query = secondlist
print("Second part of the query will be like: " + second_part_of_the_query)


#Try to join the queries
query = "INSERT INTO testtale " + first_part_of_query + " VALUES " + second_part_of_the_query
print("Query looks like: " + query)
val = datte
mycursor.execute(query, val)
db.commit()
```

CODE PRINTS

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to pass `thelist` in to mycursor.execute rather than `datte`? I'm not sure what mysql library you are using but it seems odd for the params to be provided as a dict rather than an ordered list.

Comment: @Rob Streeting, your comment has opened my eyes and it has worked, I am so used to using a dictionary format of passing mysql values but this implementation requires a python list, all I had to do was convert datte into an ordered list and it has worked. I can't thank you enough, i have edited the question with the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rob Streeting suggested,

I have converted my dictionary into an ordered list then to a tuple like so

```
print("Dictionary is: " + str(datte))
list = []
for value in datte.values():
    list.append(value)

listintotupple = tuple(list)
print(listintotupple)
```

Then passed it to the query:

```
#Try to join the queries
query = "INSERT INTO testtale " + first_part_of_query + " VALUES " + second_part_of_the_query
print("Query looks like: " + query)
val = listintotupple
mycursor.execute(query, val)
db.commit()
```